# Presto odbc failing to read timestamp fileds in HIVE

Tags: hive, odbc, presto, presto-jdbc

I am using presto ODBC to fetch data from Hive into one of the BI tools, however, the query fails with the below error. Could you please help me to understand what might be the issue.

ODBC version: Simba Presto ODBC Driver 1.02.09.1009

used sql : select created_ts from stg_tables.vend

Jul 07 08:07:03.919 ERROR 500 Statement::SQLPrepareW: [Simba][Presto] (1070) Unknown Presto data type: timestamp(3)

While if I am using below SQL it goes good.
select  to_iso8601(created_ts AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') from stg_tables.ven

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of Presto added support for variable precision timestamp types. Unfortunately, Simba's ODBC driver makes certain assumptions about how the type names are presented to the client and fails with the new types.

The next release of Presto (coming out this week) will have [a configuration option](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/pull/4349) to restore the old behavior while we give client implementations a chance to upgrade their implementations if they made similar assumptions.

**Update**: this should now fixed in [version 338](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/release/release-338.html#general-changes). You can set the `deprecated.omit-datetime-type-precision` config option to `true` to restore the old behavior.